# Stop a CSS rotate animation smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I created this sample css class for roate an image indefinitely :

```
.rotate{
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

I add this class to an image in my html page. Shortly after I want stop the rotation smoothly from unknown keyframe. I must create another css class like that :

```
.rotateToStop{
    ...
}
```

and from javascript code :

```
$('myelement').addClass('rotate');
// ... 
// shortly after, when an specific event is triggered
$('myelement').removeClass('rotate');
$('myelement').addClass('rotateToStop');
```

but I haven't any ideas how I do in the css 'rotateToStop' class , someone can help me ? =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't stop animation smoothly if you just remove animation from an element by removing the class.

But you can stop animation using this:

```
.rotateToStop {
  animation-play-state: paused; 
}
```

In this case you shouldn't remove `.rotate` class but have to toggle a class that starts or pauses animation.

One problem: animation will freeze exactly at the moment you add needed class.

Comment: Okay and indeed, I don't want stop exactly :)